# Swing - Get URL used by ImageProducer to produce an Image

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I am trying to get to the url of an Image.

```
Icon icon = getIcon(); // gets a previously initialised Icon 
ImageIcon imageIcon = (ImageIcon) icon;
Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
image.getSource(); // returns a java.awt.image.FilteredImageSource
```

The `FilteredImageSource` has a property `src`, which contains the url of the image. 
However the src property is with default access modifier.

Is there any way I can get the image url at this point in time ?

Comment: going dirty and use reflection? Obviously not recommended, but if you are desparate ;-)

Comment: Thanks @kleopatra . Dirty as it may be, that did the job